# delete multiple checkbox using codeigniter and ajax without form

Tags: ajax, forms, codeigniter

I'm trying to delete multiple id from my database by selecting multiple checkboxes in the datatable and clicking button to delete. I have the code below but got an error 400 (bad request) http://localhost/ra/member/ajax_delete/**1615,1614** where 1615,1614 are my id want to delete, here is my code :

Views :

```
....
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="id[]" value="'.$paket->id.'"/></td>    
....
    <button type="button" value="Click" id="btntest">Delete All</button>

<script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready(function() {
            function getCheckboxesValues(){
                return [].slice.apply(document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]"))
                       .filter(function(c){ return c.checked; })
                       .map(function(c){ return c.value; });
            }
            document.getElementById("btntest").addEventListener("click", function(){
                delete_paket(getCheckboxesValues());
            });

        function delete_paket(id)
        {
                    // ajax delete data to database
                    $.ajax({
                        url : "<?php echo site_url('member/ajax_delete')?>/"+id,
                        type: "POST",
                        dataType: "JSON",
                        success: function(data)
                        {
                            //if success reload ajax table
                            $('#modal_form').modal('hide');
                            reload_table();
                        },
                        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
                        {
                            alert('Error deleting data');
                        }
                    });
                } 
            })
        }

            </script>
```

controller :

```
public function ajax_delete($id)
{
    $this->load->model('mem_data','paket')
    $this->paket->delete_by_id($id);
    echo json_encode(array("status" => TRUE));
}
```

Models :

```
    public function delete_by_id($id)
{
    $this->db->where_in('id', $id);
    $this->db->delete($this->table);
}
```

My code work just for 1 checkbox not for multiple checkbox, please help me

Comment: I would pass the ID's as a single string, and then `explode` it on the PHP side and loop through to delete each row.

Comment: how to do that sir? many thanks